# $\nu(A)=m(f^{-1}(A))$ when $m$ Lebesgue measure and $f(x)=x^{3}$. Is $\nu<<m$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f(x)=x^{3}$,$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

For every measurable set  $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we define a measure: $$\nu(A)=m(f^{-1}(A))$$

Is it true that $\nu<<m$ ?

=======================================================================================

Well, I thought this is true mainly because I couldn't find any proper counterexample (perhaps some variation of Cantor set?).

Let  $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set so $m(A)=0$. Obviously Lebesgue measure is not invariant under $\sqrt[3]{.}$ (also $f$ is invertible, of course), but it might be the case for sets of zero measure.

I tried using the fact that:
$$
\nu(A)=m(f^{-1}(A))=inf\Big\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty(b_j-a_j) : f^{-1}(A) \subset\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty(a_j,b_j) \Big\}
=inf\Big\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty(\sqrt[3]{b_j}-\sqrt[3]{a_j}) : A \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty(a_j,b_j) \Big\}
$$

While knowing that:
$$m(A)=inf\Big\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty(b_j-a_j) : A \subset\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty(a_j,b_j) \Big\}=0$$

But no progression from here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\nu([a,b])=\int_{[a,b]}\frac{x^{-2/3}}{3}\lambda(dx)$

Comment: Thanks. Does it imply that this equation is true for every measurable A and not just intervals? Then it's immediate. Thanks again.

Comment: I would think about uniqueness of measures and how lhs and rhs are both measures

Comment: Got it. Thanks to the uniqueness of Borel measures. Thanks!